# Use different colour in part of a time series plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying unsuccessfully to apply different colour a for distinct part of my time series plot. Below is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame('date' = as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01')),
                    'value' = c(10, 5, 12, 2, 23),
                    'Part' = c('NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES'))

ggplot(data = dat) +
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value, color = Part))
```

With this I am getting below plot,

[image]

However I wanted to get a single line plot with different colour based on the column `Part` in data.

Is there any way to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is saying `group = 1` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = value, color = Part, group = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This solution is more intuitive. Thanks for this.